# Is it possible to autoincrement a certain column value in Microsoft Word Tables?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

I have a big table on a MS Word 2007 document. The left most column is named 'serial' and it's values increment starting from one. Now, this can be achieved automatically in Excel, is this possible with MS Word tables?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to do it in Word, but it is possible to copy the Excel table to Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the feature isn't directly implemented in MS Word table. As of now, the best bet is to use external auto listing, such as those from Excel. And of course, there is the good old way of doing it manually.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any built-in feature for this, but there is a great alternative. By far the easiest way is to use Microsoft Word auto numbering.

If you start a numbered list in the first column and then "tab" over several times to start a new row you will find the numbering continues in the next row of the same column which is a really nice feature. Also, you get all the benefits which come with auto numbering such as being able to use different appearances and change the starting number, both of which are a plus.